# Issues passing props via react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-props

I am attempting to pass data via react-router-dom, specifically I wanted to hold state data in the App.js file which I am using to route to different pages. I can't get the props to pass. What am I doing off here? Below is an example of what I am trying to do:

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Home from './Home';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route,Switch, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      testProps:7
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Route 
            exact path="/" 
            component = {Home} 
            render={(props) => <Home testProps={this.state.testProps} {...props}  />}/>
       </div>
      </Router>

    );
  }
}
```

export default App;

**Home.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {`passing props from state: ${this.props.testProps}`}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Home;
```

In my home page I see: `passing props from state: undefined`. Am I approaching this incorrectly?

Comment: You're using both `component` and `render`. Remove the component prop.

Comment: Thank you, very silly mistake.